# What's the problem of saving pointer of vector inside std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, memoization

I am trying to find the best sum with memorization, but when saving the vector pointer inside a map the values keep appending inside the vector and getting the wrong vector.
if I commented out the map insertion it works properly.
saving nullptr is not possible in case trying to save vector inside the map by reference.

```
std::vector<int> *bestSumV(int target, int nums[], int size) {

  static std::map<int, std::vector<int> *> memo;

  if (memo.find(target) != memo.end())
    return memo.at(target);

  if (target == 0)
    return new std::vector<int>();

  if (target < 0)
    return NULL;

  std::vector<int> *bestCom = nullptr;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    int reminder = target - nums[i];

    std::vector<int> *reminderResult = bestSumV(reminder, nums, size);

    if (reminderResult != NULL) {

      reminderResult->push_back(nums[i]);

      if (bestCom == nullptr || reminderResult->size() < bestCom->size()) {
        bestCom = static_cast<std::vector<int> *>(reminderResult);
      }
    }
  }
  // if i commented out the map insertion i am getting the correct value
  // and getting a vector of 5 items

  memo.insert(std::make_pair(target, std::move(bestCom)));

  return bestCom;
}

void runHowbestTest() {

  int testArray[] = {5, 4, 2};

  std::vector<int> *bestSum25 = bestSumV(25, testArray, 3);

  for (int i = 0; i < bestSum25->size(); i++) {
    std::cout << "the items  " << bestSum25->at(i) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: i bet on too many pointers being the problem. Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: Use `std::map<int , std::vector<int>>` instead. To make it faster, and easier to not make a mistake.

Comment: I tried std::vector<int> but during memorization, but I need to save nullptr which is not possible in the case of std::map<int, std::vector<int>> @eerorika

Comment: why do you *need*  to store a nullptr? If you want en "empty" element, cant you store an empty vector at that position in the map?

Comment: @youssefmyh Besides what largest_prime suggested, how about not storing an element in that case? If neither of those are an option, then use `std::optional<std::vector>` and store `nullopt`.

Comment: return an empty vector will break the target check @largest_prime_is_463035818.
I will try nullopt and std::optional<std::vector>@eerorika may be it works.

Comment: @youssefmyh *return an empty vector will break the target check* -- In other words, you wrote the code, and now you've painted yourself into a corner.  Memoization is just a technique -- you decided to use `nullptr` -- someone else would have decided to use an empty vector, and would have written the code to handle it.

Comment: I dont completely understand the code, but I have the feeling that you are using pointers to vectors mainly to have `bestSumV` return, in addition to the resulting vector, also a success flag. Thats not (anymore) what you should use a nullptr for. As mentioned `std::optional` can be used to optionally return a value

Comment: pointers or not, you should not dynamically allocate standard containers. This is almost always a mistake. At least prefer smart pointers over raw `new` (and `delete`)

Comment: @youssefmyh Also, if you knew nothing about `std::optional`, you could have returned a `std::pair`, where the `first` could be the vector, and the `second` would be a `bool` denoting whether the vector is valid, or "null".  That's how a few of the STL container functions work.

Comment: std::optional<std::vector<int>> is working prefectly the only problem it's only available on c++17 @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @youssefmyh Well `std::pair` works in any C++ standard.

Comment: @youssefmyh `std::pair<std::vector<int>, bool> bestSumV(int target, int nums[], int size) {...return { {}, false }};` -- that effectively returns a pair of an empty vector and `false`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie std::pair<std::vector<int>, bool> looks interesting , will try it

Thanks a lot

Comment: @youssefmyh If you cannot have C++17 yet, then you can use a non-standard implementation of optional.

Comment: std::tuple , std::pair<std::vector<int>, bool> are working perfectly 
also std::optional is working prefectly

Thanks a lot, guys you made my day

Comment: when you `if (target == 0) return new std::vector<int>();`, it always returns a new vector. Those vectors are never put in the map

Comment: The vector inserted inside the map once the bestSumV function finished.
I am inserting only inside the map the bestCom which I need.

Answer (score 0):

`bestCom` is a `std::vector<int> *` don't `std::move` it. It's pointless, and makes the code hard to read.

`reminderResult` is already a `std::vector<int> *`, no need to `static_cast<std::vector<int> *>` it.

On this line

```
memo.insert(std::make_pair(target, std::move(bestCom)));
```

`bestCom` might be null. When that happens,

```
if (memo.find(target) != memo.end())
    return memo.at(target);
```

will return and bypass the function logic. You need:

```
if (memo.find(target) != memo.end() && memo.at(target))
    return memo.at(target);
```

And, most likely, the real issue:

```
// returns a memoized value
std::vector<int> *reminderResult = bestSumV(reminder, nums, size); 
...
  // modifies it.
  reminderResult->push_back(nums[i]);
```

You cannot modify a memoized value and expect it to be valid.

Using objects instead of pointers fixes the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/v35oT4 . But I make no claims about what it does to performance.

Comment: not saying that this is wrong (I really dont know), but "return and bypass the function logic" is just what `memo` is used for. If it contains a `nullptr` for key `target` then only because it has been inserted after passing the functions logic on a previous call

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 memo is used to reduce the time complexity from O(n^m) to O(n*m) 

Thanks a lot for your comment i see that std::move and static_cast is useless